# Creating a list of all commits from which a branch has been made using bash

Tags: git, bash, sed, diff

I'm looking for a list containing:

- Date
- Branch Name

For all branches coming off 'develop' with 'release' in the name.

similar to

```
2014-03-11 10:52:04 +0100 9 months ago  release-1.0
2014-03-28 10:33:23 +0100 8 months ago  release-2.0
2014-04-02 10:40:59 +0200 8 months ago  release-3.0
2014-04-18 17:01:54 +0200 8 months ago  release-3.0.1
2014-05-05 15:25:31 +0200 7 months ago  release-3.0.2
```

I've found several answers which have really helped me, and now I'm stumbling on syntax. Useful information was:

- [Finding Tail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25298040/linux-head-tail-with-offset)
- [Show *active* git branches by date](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/2345/show-git-branches-by-date-useful-for-showing-active-branches) (note that I'm looking for the commit at which the branch was made)
- [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9979346) in another post

So far I have the following as an alias in bash

```
for k in `git branch|sed s/^..//`;
    do  echo -e `git log -1 --pretty=format:"%Cgreen%ci %Cblue%cr %Creset" 
         <(`diff -u <(git rev-list --first-parent "$k") <(git rev-list --first-parent develop)|sed -ne '"'"'s/^ //p'"'"'|head -1`)
           --`\\t"$k";

done|sort;'
```

running each part of this individually works. But not altogether.

So these work:

- `git branch|sed s/^..//`
- `git log -1 --pretty=format:"%Cgreen%ci %Cblue%cr %Creset" release-3.0`
- `diff -u <(git rev-list --first-parent release-3.0) <(git rev-list --first-parent develop)`

But not when I put them together.

Help?

Comment: You cannot nest backtick commands like this. `\`echo foo \`echo bar\` baz\``. To nest you need to use the `$()` syntax.

Comment: But why are you using `echo -e` here at all anyway? Can you not just put `\t$k` in the git log format string?

Comment: Don't use an alias for something that complex; use a shell function.

Comment: @EtanReisner I think that did it! I wasn't using \t$k because I just don't know enough to do this efficiently. I'm happy with effective just now.

Comment: @chepner now that I know how to do this with an alias I'll probably turn it into a function. Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to feed `git log` input from standard input (that diff command)? Because I don't think git log does that.

Comment: @chepner, using some of Etan's work I turned it into a function in the end. Thanks: https://gist.github.com/TheMightyLlama/7e300149a901c3ee5642

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot nest backtick commands like this:

```
echo `echo foo `echo bar` baz`
```

To nest you need to use the (all around more preferable) `$()` syntax.

You also don't need backticks inside a
    <(`...`)

unless you want the substitution to run the **output** from the `...` command instead of the `...` command itself.

So try something more like this:

```
for k in $(git branch|sed s/^..//);
    do  echo -e $(git log -1 --pretty=format:"%Cgreen%ci %Cblue%cr %Creset" 
         <(`diff -u <(git rev-list --first-parent "$k") <(git rev-list --first-parent develop)|sed -ne '"'"'s/^ //p'"'"'|head -1`)
           --)\\t"$k";
done|sort;'
```

Or without the `<()` backticks

```
for k in $(git branch|sed s/^..//);
    do echo -e $(git log -1 --pretty=format:"%Cgreen%ci %Cblue%cr %Creset" 
         <(diff -u <(git rev-list --first-parent "$k") <(git rev-list --first-parent develop)|sed -ne '"'"'s/^ //p'"'"'|head -1)
           --)\\t"$k";
done|sort;'
```

Additionally, I don't think you need to use `echo -e` here at all since you can probably just put the `\t$k` in the `git log` format string directly.

```
for k in $(git branch|sed s/^..//); do
    git log -1 --pretty=format:"%Cgreen%ci %Cblue%cr %Creset"$'\t'"$k" 
         <(diff -u <(git rev-list --first-parent "$k") <(git rev-list --first-parent develop)|sed -ne '"'"'s/^ //p'"'"'|head -1)
           --;
done|sort;'
```

Which, assuming I did that all right, looks like it is trying to feed `git log` the revision to log from standard input but I don't believe `git log` takes input that way. So you would need to make it an argument instead.

```
for k in $(git branch|sed s/^..//); do
    git log -1 --pretty=format:"%Cgreen%ci %Cblue%cr %Creset"$'\t'"$k" 
         "$(diff -u <(git rev-list --first-parent "$k") <(git rev-list --first-parent develop)|sed -ne '"'"'s/^ //p'"'"'|head -1)"
         --;
done|sort;'
```

And you can probably get rid of that dangling `--` too.

Comment: @TomFenech Honestly, I'm not sure what that is. The snippet in the OP isn't complete (it leaves off the alias prefix at very least) and the quoting issues are confusing me. I can try though.

Comment: The reason I mentioned it was that I was considering making an answer which combined usage of `$()` and a function myself but got a bit confused too!